# Could not find rake-11.1.2 in rails docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm running two docker containers. One with rails and one with Postgres db.
Here is my docker-compose file:

```
# Docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxx

  rails:
    build: .
    command: rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Here the Dockerfile for the rails app:

```
FROM ruby:2.3

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs 

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./ 
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

When I run `docker-compose up` everything works fine and I can connect to the server via the ip address from docker-machine.

When I try to connect to the container with the following command:

```
docker-compose run rails console
```

I get this error:

```
Could not find rake-11.1.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

bundle install inside the container has no effect and the mentioned gem is definitely installed. In other stack-overflow questions were mentioned that I should run `bin/spring stop`. So I ran:

```
docker-compose run bin/spring stop
```

And it returns:

```
Spring is not running
```

I'm still comparibly new to ruby/rails and docker. I hope someone can help me here!
Thanks in advance

PS: Comments on the Dockerfiles are appreciated!

Comment: I have the exact same issue!

Answer (score 2):

seems to be a late response but I will answer anyway. My educated guess is that your `Gemfile.lock` is pinning your `rake` version and that is why it is complaining. If you run the `docker build` without a volume defined like in your `docker-compose.yml` you can easily end up like this. So give it a try.

In regard to your `Dockerfile`: If you use this only for development purposes then this might be ok. Otherwise you should think about running it using a different user (create user with `useradd` and run `RUN` tasks and so on accordingly). You might also want to use some bundler features like the `--path=<path>` option.

Comment: ive tried setting a user, it didnt work. bundle install now throws permission error with the new user

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same problem. Even though Spring said it was not running, my colleague pointed out to me if I looked into `bin/rails` I'd see that it would, in fact, run with Rails. Removing the `spring` related gems in `Gemfile` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using this command in my `Dockerfile`.

```
RUN bundle install --without development test --with runtime --deployment
```